# Sql / Finding Min Max values for each elements of another column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Learning sql, as per title trying to print min and max values of a given column (sal) for each values in another (nodept). Using this query so far:

```
SELECT Nodept, sal FROM emp
WHERE sal IN ((SELECT MAX (sal) FROM emp), (SELECT MIN (sal) FROM emp))
```

Which works but only returns absolute min max and not min max for every entry in nodept. Documentation says it should be a simple matter of adding GROUP BY to the query but i fail to find the syntax for it.

Ty for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want

```
select nodept, min(sal) min_sal, max(sal) max_sal
from   emp
group by nodept
```

If you want a row for each `min` and `max` per `nodept` then you want to add a filter to your subqueries:

```
SELECT Nodept, sal 
FROM   emp e1
WHERE e1.sal IN ((SELECT MAX (sal) FROM emp e2 where e2.nodept = e1.nodept)
                ,(SELECT MIN (sal) FROM emp e2 where e2.nodept = e1.nodept)
                )
```