# min, max, avg and count given the values in another column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Learning SQL, still stuck. I previously asked a similar question :
[Sql / Finding Min Max values for each elements of another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72176836/sql-finding-min-max-values-for-each-elements-of-another-column)

I'm now trying to find, a query that lists Dept name (nomdep), gives Min, Max and AVG salary(SAL) for each department, counts the number of employees(count(nomemp)) per department, the number of those that touches a bonus(COMM) per department and finally the number of jobs(emploi) per. I tried this, which unsurprisingly only gives min max etc table wide and not relative per department.

```
SELECT Nomdept,  MIN(SAL), MAX(SAL), AVG(SAL) AS Average_Salary,  
COUNT(Nomemp), COUNT(COMM IS NOT NULL), COUNT(EMPLOI)

FROM EMP, DEPT
GROUP BY Nomdept
ORDER BY Nomdept
```

Thinking it must then be done with subqueries and following the previous post's answer, I attempted this approach:

```
SELECT Nodept, sal
FROM   emp e1
WHERE e1.sal IN ((SELECT MAX (sal) FROM emp e2 where nodept = 30)
                ,(SELECT MIN (sal) FROM emp e2 where nodept = 30)
                ,(SELECT AVG (sal) FROM emp e2 where nodept = 30)
                ,(SELECT MAX (sal) FROM emp e2 where nodept = 20)
                ,(SELECT MIN (sal) FROM emp e2 where nodept = 20)
                ,(SELECT AVG (sal) FROM emp e2 where nodept = 20)
                ,(SELECT MAX (sal) FROM emp e2 where nodept = 10)
                ,(SELECT MIN (sal) FROM emp e2 where nodept = 10)
                ,(SELECT AVG (sal) FROM emp e2 where nodept = 10)
                )  

ORDER BY Nodept
```

But the averages gets scrapped already and it feels a very inelegant way to do it. Ideally the query would not require for the dept number to be input manually. There has to be a simple way to add a per department condition

As always grateful for any and all inputs.

Comment: Your first query is correct: min(sal) would return the minimum salary within the department. Show us an example where it gives 'absolute' numbers.

Comment: Well there are multiple departments and each end up with the same min max and avg when they should not. The second query returns adequate number per departments but feels like a wrong method for such a query. I was indeed under the impression that this was correct syntax

Comment: Your first query is the correct approach but it’s not working because you’ve referenced 2 tables but not actually joined them, which will generate a cartesian product; also none of your columns reference which tabke they are being sourced from. When you do correct your SQL, make sure to use ANSI join syntax and not the old Oracle join syntax - which was deprecated 30 years ago and not considered good practice

Comment: I am sorry I didn't realise that you query was specifying two tables: EMP, DEPT. Where is the JOIN condition? you should have a condition specifying which row in DEPT is joined to which row in EMP, maybe EMP.DEPT_NO=DEPT.DEPT_NO (we don't know your data model). Ideally this condition is given as FROM EMP E JOIN DEPT D ON E.DEPT_NO=D.DEPT_NO

Comment: Mea culpa, i should have specified and provided the  full length tables. Indeed, I'm going of material that mixes oracle mysql and psql together along with deprecated commands . It's always slightly wrong somehow. I did try using a join condition in that exact form to no avail. I will update post as i'm able with further data but then i'd like to do it with an online sql tool like sql fiddle which will take me a bit. Ty for your time and clarification anyway.